# an error while trying to play an audio in Audio Playback Agent. System.SystemException: HRESULT = 0xC00D001A

Tags: c#, audio, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I want to play an audio in background.

So I did this iniside my main project

```
BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Track = audioTrack;
BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Play();
```

and inside audio background agent:

```
protected override void OnUserAction(BackgroundAudioPlayer player, AudioTrack track, UserAction action, object param)
{
    switch (action)
    {
        case UserAction.Play:
            player.Play();
            break;
        case UserAction.Stop:
            player.Stop();
            break;
        case UserAction.Pause:
            player.Pause();
            break;
        case UserAction.FastForward:
            player.FastForward();
            break;
        case UserAction.Rewind:
            player.Rewind();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    NotifyComplete();
}
```

but I get an error:

> System.SystemException: HRESULT = 0xC00D001A

I have another question too: will this continue playing after I close the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error code should say it all:

- `0xC00D001A`
- [`NS_E_FILE_NOT_FOUND`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc704587.aspx)
- "The system cannot find the file specified."